# Upgrade Scrum 2.1 process template to Scrum (TFS 2107)

Tags: visual-studio, templates, tfs

I've been using TFS 2012 to create a team project that uses Scrum 2.1. I recently upgraded to TFS 2017. I want to configure my Test Plan, but when I go to configure parameters for it, TFS tells me that I need to upgrade the Template

[image: I need to upgrade the Template]

I've downloaded the Scrum 2017 template, taking it from the server installation. I also downloaded the Scrum 2.1 template. Most guides I've read suggests that carefully I need to copy and paste my custom XML from the current template to the new one. 
But I have never customized the 2.1 template. Can I simply override the 2.1 files with the new Scrum 2017 files?
Otherwise, which files are the most likely I should change?

Comment: What impact will it have for you if the Test Plan becomes to Work Item?
Generally you can’t simply override the 2.1 files with the new Scrum 2017 files, after a TFS upgrade, some new features were installed, some of these features might require updates to your team project. If Test Plan and Test Suite are not configured, you'll need to manually import the WIT definitions and migrate data.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn789837.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t override the process template as you said. You need to upgrade the process template. If it can’t upgrade automatically, you need to apply updates manually.

More information, you can refer to: [Configure features after an upgrade](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade).

You can open new threads on Stack Overflow or MSDN forum if there are issues that you can’t fix, we can help you to deal with these issues.